# usage of libsvm-matlab version

Tags: matlab, libsvm

Based on the readme file in the libsvm package. The svmpredict matlab version function is used in the following way:

```
[predicted_label, accuracy, decision_values/prob_estimates] =
svmpredict(testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix, model [,
'libsvm_options']);
```

The return value "accuracy" is always a three dimension vector. The first element in the vector
is the classification accuracy. What are the other two?

Can I use the decision_values as the confidence score? Or prob_estimates?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you read [down in the README a bit](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/matlab/README#L135):

> ## Result of Prediction
>
> The function 'svmpredict' has three outputs. The first one,
>   predictd_label, is a vector of predicted labels. The second output,
>   accuracy, is a vector including accuracy (for classification), mean
>   squared error, and squared correlation coefficient (for regression).

If you're doing classification, you should only care about the first component.

`decision_values` are confidence scores, by definition. They represent how far past the margin the test points lie. `prob_estimates`, when using `-b 1` in the `libsvm_options` to turn them on, are monotonic transformations of `decision values` (which can be any real number, where 0 is the dividing line between the classes) to probabilities (between 0 and 1, with 0.5 the dividing line).

Comment: Exactly this. The manual is clear about these things (+1).